# Ubuntu 20.04 from 19.10

Tags: 19.10

I was going to upgrade to 20.04 from my recently install 19.10, but when I run sudo do-release-upgrade it tells me there is no LTS version to install. Is 20.04 not ready for server installation? I am running a cloud server with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrades between LTS releases are not enabled by default until the first point release, scheduled for July. It is recommended that most LTS users wait until then before upgrading to 20.04

If you choose to upgrade before then, you can pass the -d option to the upgrade tool, running |do-release-upgrade -d or update-manager -d.